# Setup Konva with Jest

Tags: jestjs, konvajs, ts-jest, ts-node, konva

I'm trying to setup Jest with Konva, but getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stage' of undefined

  88 |     }
  89 |
> 90 |     const stage = new Konva.Stage({
```

I have imported Konva with `import Konva from 'konva'` in my TS file, and it works when I change that to `import * as Konva from 'konva'`

Is there a workaround to fix this module resolution on Jest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added these properties to my `tsconfig.json` and the issue resolved:

```
{
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "esModuleInterop": true
}
```